# Clear the Session after Complete page got reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I have a session variable like this `$_SESSION['ids'];`

My goal is to clear that Cookie when the page got reload/redirected to some other page.

Using `unset($_SESSION['ids']);` its working but the problem is not for page reload for each & every ajax/response also.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Hi use this link to detect the ajax request. http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax

Comment: unset session during onsuccess response again.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) 
      && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') 
{ 
 // Not an ajax request
  unset($_SESSION['ids']);
}
```